# Nextjs deployed on Vercel = blank page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-deployment, netlify, vercel

I managed to deploy my Nextjs app (whith getStaticProps + i18n + firebase) on Vercel.
But i get a blank screen.
Here's the log:

```
Status: 200
Duration: 8.18ms
Memory Used: 111 MB
```

I tried :

- Checking the build function locally: it works perfectly.
- Changing the default build and development settings to these (with no luck) :

[image]

- I even tried to deploy on netlify (even thought i don't think they support i18n because i18n doesn't support next export), but i get a 404 page, which is the equivalent of a blank page in Vercel.

I also tried:

1. Creating a new git and re-deploying. But I still get an empty result after a perfect deploy with a list of all my pages and stuff...
2. Deleting i18n.
3. Deleting index.html from public
4. Deleting all pages but one.
5. Deleting _document.jsx
6. Deleting every public folder pages except assets like images.
7. Deleting package lock file.
   Stil nothing works.
   And yet, i get a perfect previw of my webapp in Vercel, but the link goes to a blank page.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Try adding some relevant code because otherwise we can't help you debug.

Comment: It is impossible to debug this without proper context or minimal repro. Please check the guidelines of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It was impossible to add codes since my local code was running without error, and the proejct is too big to be shared here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake.
It was a problem with my getServerSideProps code

To this :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  const data = cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || "" : document.cookie);

  if (res) {
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object) {
      res.end();
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { userId: data.userId }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

I went to this:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  const data = cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || "" : document.cookie);

  return {
    props: { userId: data.userId }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

The **res.end();** was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Deleting the following worked for me:

```js
"homepage": "https://your-username.github.io/the-repo-project/",
```

2. vercel --prod
3. You have to wait a minute

But I think it depends on the project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue of having a blank page. I later discovered that I was running "npm run dev" in the wrong directory.
Instead of `cd C:\wamp\www\projectname`, I typed `cd c:\wamp\www\projectname`.
The difference is capital letter "C". Small letter "c" won't work.
Ensure your casing (capital or small) is right and everything spelt correctly. Then, run "npm run dev" and see your expected page display (if there are no other errors hindering it from showing).

Answer (score 0):

For a while, I encountered a consistent issue where some users could view my MERN stack app deployed on Vercel, while others complained of a blank page. I was able to resolve this issue by following these steps:

1. I added the following code to the app's BrowserRouter component: `<BrowserRouter basename="/">`. This helped to ensure that the app's routes were correctly resolved.
2. I removed the "homepage" attribute from the frontend package.json file. This attribute can sometimes cause issues with app deployment on Vercel, and removing it can help to resolve such issues.